# What is the meaning of <#= #>

Tags: asp.net, .net, syntax, expression, t4

Reading [Code Generation and T4 Text Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) and I found this syntax <#= DateTime.Now #>

```
<html><body>
 The date and time now is: <#= DateTime.Now #>
</body></html>
```

How is it different from `<%= DateTime.Now %>` or `<%# DateTime.Now %>`.

Google search showed nothing

Comment: going through the documentation, it has all the syntax of `<% %>`. Very identical.

Comment: During T4 text generation <#=DateTime.Now#> is evaluated and the result is written to the output. AFAIK <%= %> means nothing to the T4 Engine and is just written as is.

Comment: @FuleSnabel I didn't know the difference, I am new to T4, I thought it's another way of writing expression is asp.net. Was just strange to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't claim to be really familiar with T4 text templates, but it appears the difference is between design/build time code generation (which can include executable statements) and runtime code execution.

So `<#= #>` evaluates an expression within a template that is used to generate a file.

And `<%= %>` executes the code within the block and writes it to the output stream. This will be JIT-compiled when the page is first executed, but the point is that it denotes a block of code to execute when the page runs, not during generation of a templated file.

The third form, `<%# %>` denotes a databinding expression, also evaluated when the page executes.

> **Expression control blocks**
>
> An expression control block evaluates an expression and converts it to
>   a string. This is inserted into the output file.
>
> Expression control blocks are delimted by the symbols <#= ... #>
>
> For example, the following control block causes the output file to
>   contain "5":
>
> `<#= 2 + 3 #>`

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126478

Comment: You mean `<#= 2 + 3 #>` is the same as `<%= 2 + 3 %>`?

Comment: The end result in the output is the same, but the evaluation happens at different times. `<#= 2+3` would execute when you generated a file, so your generated file would have "5" in it. `<%= 2+3` will execute when you run an ASP.Net page.

Comment: For example, it would be the difference between inserting a timestamp when the code is built versus evaluating the current date each time the page is executed.

Comment: brilliant response. going through the documentation, it has all the syntax of `<% %>`. Very identical.